# Relative position from two reference frames

Tags: kinematics, relative-motion

[image]

Here, clearly $\vec{r}_{S'S} + \vec{r}_{PS'}= \vec{r}_{PS}$. Then we differentiate and double differentiate and get the standard equations of relative velocity and acceleration.

Now according to my understanding $y$ and $y'$ must be parallel, similarly $x$ and $x'$ must be parallel. If that's not the case then we might as well rotate frame S' at any angle as long as origin is fixed and we would still get same equations (because vectors are being measured from origin and they don't care how the rest of the frame is). Does that mean all those reference frames are equivalent? If not, we can only use the relative motion equations for such frames that have parallel axes? Also both S and S' should be rectangular frames right?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: The diagram shows $\vec{r}_{PS} = \vec{r}_{S'S} + \vec{r}_{PS'}$ where $r_{ij}$ means $i$ is the arrow and $j$ the tail. That is not what your notionation is as you have flipped the arrow and tail for $\vec{r}_{PS}$ and $\vec{r}_{PS'}$ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add vectors, they need to be on a common vector basis. That is to say the components have to be measured along parallel axis *x*, *y*, etc. As such, the coordinate frames are just reduced to just points in space, as their orientation does not matter (or has been accounted for by rotations).

But because you are measuring distances, you have two *points* to measure from/to. Using the coordinate frame *S'* origin as just a point in space accomplices this by decomposing the distance from frame *S* origin to point *P* into two parts.

The convention in the diagram is $ \vec{r}_\text{(to)(from)} $ as in $\vec{r}_{PS}$ the distaces of *P* from *S*.

So the equation shown in the diagram is

$$ \vec{r}_{PS} = \vec{r}_{S'S} + \vec{r}_{PS'} $$

to be interpreted as

- The distance of *P* from *S* is decomposed into the distance of *S'* from *S* and *P* from *S'*.

  If you assume all is moving then you can differentiate to get

  $$ \vec{v}_{PS} = \vec{v}_{S'S} + \vec{v}_{PS'} $$

  and

  $$ \vec{a}_{PS} = \vec{a}_{S'S} + \vec{a}_{PS'} $$

---

#### Non-aligned coordinate systems *S* and *S'*

Suppose the orientation of *S'* is given relative to *S* based on a {3×3} matrix $\mathbf{R}_{S'}^S$. It might be helpful to use a superscript ${\square}^\text{(frame)}$ to denote the coordinate basis vectors where the components are measured.

For example, $\vec{r}_{PS'}^{S'}$ is the location of *P* relative to *S'* in the *S'* coordinate frame. An in the *S* coordinate frame you have

$$ \underbrace{ \vec{r}_{PS'}^{S}}_\text{inertial} = \mathbf{R}_{S'}^{S} \underbrace{ \vec{r}_{PS'}^{S'} }_\text{body} $$

The above is rather busy for my taste, so I usually drop any labels referring to the inertial coordinate system (the *S* frame in this case) and also assume all vectors originate from the origin of their frame. Using this convention the above simplifies to

$$ \underbrace{ \vec{r}_{P}}_\text{inertial} = \mathbf{R}_{S'} \underbrace{ \vec{r}_{P}^{S'} }_\text{body} $$

<sub>If I *need* to designate a vector between two points *P* and *Q* in some frame *F* then I use the vector subtraction instead $ \vec{r}_{PQ}^F = \vec{r}_P^F - \vec{r}_Q^F $.</sub>

The full decomposition of point *P* becomes

$$ \vec{r}_P = \vec{r}_{S'} + \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{r}_P^{S'} $$

and considering the point might be moving in the *S'* frame with some velocity $\vec{v}_P^{S'}$ and the frame *S'* might be rotating in the *S* frame with $\vec{\omega}_{S'}$ then

$$ \vec{v}_P = \vec{v}_{S'} + \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{v}_P^{S'} + \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{r}_P^{S'} $$

But since the position kinematics are known, it is easier to re-write the above as follows considering another derivative is going needed after for acceleration.

$$ \vec{v}_P = \vec{v}_{S'} + \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times (\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_{S'}) + \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{v}_P^{S'} $$

Finally, for the acceleration consider the parts above as follows using the product rule of differentiation

- $\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \left[ \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times (\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_{S'}) \right] = \vec{\alpha}_{S'} \times (\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_{S'}) + \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times (\vec{v}_P - \vec{v}_{S'})$
- $\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \left[ \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{v}_P^{S'} \right] = \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{v}_P^{S'} + \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{a}_P^{S'}$

and altogether

$$ \vec{a}_P = \vec{a}_{S'} +  \vec{\alpha}_{S'} \times (\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_{S'}) + \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times (\vec{v}_P - \vec{v}_{S'}) + \vec{\omega}_{S'} \times \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{v}_P^{S'} + \mathbf{R}_{S'} \vec{a}_P^{S'}$$

the above can also be stated as

$$\vec{a}_{P}=\vec{a}_{S'}+\vec{\alpha}_{S'}\times\mathbf{R}_{S'}\vec{r}_{P}^{S'}+\vec{\omega}_{S'}\times\left(\vec{\omega}_{S'}\times\mathbf{R}_{S'}\vec{r}_{P}^{S'}\right)+2\vec{\omega}_{S'}\times\mathbf{R}_{S'}\vec{v}_{P}^{S'}+\mathbf{R}_{S'}\vec{a}_{P}^{S'}$$

Comment: Yes I messed up the vectors by mistake, I have edited that now. So you mean to say x is parallel to x' and y to y' right? Because only then we can reduce them to points and get the correct answer using the equations.

Comment: Yes, correct. Did you want me to append the answer for the situation where _S_ and _S'_ isn't aligned to each other?

Comment: Thank you for clearing it:) And yes what about that situation? For that will we have to derive personalized formula for different positions of S'?

Comment: @DhruviKataria - considering the rotation of one frame relative to another makes things a lot more complex, but by taking care of the details you can arrive at the standard equations of kinematics.